# Assign Curl command to a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl, get, nexus

I'm trying to get values from nexus and assign it to a variable using curl command

The curl command i use

`curl -u user_name:password --request GET "http://host_name:portnumber/URL`

This works as expected in postman

when i try assigning this curl command to a variable and print it with this command

```
var=$(curl -u user_name:password --request GET "http://host_name:portnumber/URL)
echo $var
```

I couldn't see the value i get when i use the curl command in postman .

Please help to on this issue . thanks in advance .

Comment: The command is missing a closing double quote.

Comment: Then, see also [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/3266847).